How to use transaction manager based on a condition while using @Transactional
I am working on a spring boot project and have a requirement where I need to choose from a set of transaction managers based on a condition(which involves @RequestParam annotated variable) and use the selected transaction manager in the 'value' attribute of @Transactional annotation on a method ?
I am unable to use variables in 'value' attribute as it allows only constant.
Any idea on how to implement this scenario ?
I tried using variables but that didn't help. I tried calling individual methods from a parent method but @Transactional didn't work as expected in called method.

This is not possible. Annotation are mean to be used with constant value only. (not really true, given the existence of SpEL, but true enough for the current problem at hand)
You will have to create a transaction programmatically, either through TransactionTemplate or directly with the wanted transaction manager. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/programmatic.html.
But first, I would think about the design of your code. Dynamically changing transaction manager for the same method struck me as a bad practice. Doesn't mean I can't think of some cases that would be needed, but I would need to think long and hard to find one of these cases.

Thanks for replying.
Any way using which we can set transaction manager within method body rather than setting in @Transactional ?
Or any suggestion in code or design that helps me in getting out of this puzzle ?

@Ankit You can access them by auto-wiring them. Check the link, it give you some exemples.
As for suggestion, cannot really help you without being part of the project. But that a piste you can explore
